# Property error in Windows phone development in C# and XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

This is a Water Hackathon, 2014 Project.
I am a newbie in windows phone. I was developing an app for a project. part of the app is that user will write his number and some text and the number and text will be emailed to a particular person.
I used drag n drop UI and wrote the code of email send in Visual C#. Here is the error:

```
Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.UIElement.AllowDrop'.[Line: 53 Position: 76]
at
System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
at
PhoneApp2.MainPage.InitializeComponent()
at PhoneApp2.MainPage..ctor()
```

part of the C# code:

```
   private void emailSend(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a new instance of the class EmailComposeTask with which you can send email
        var emailcomposer = new EmailComposeTask

        {
            // I enter the recipients to send the email using the To property of the class                         
                 EmailComposeTask
            To = string.Concat("mailto:","ibtehaz.shawon@gmail.com"),

            // Set the title of the property by Subject
            Subject = "number",

            // Enhanced the value of the Body property EmailComposeTask class, this is the 
                   content that will display the recipient
            Body = bigText.Text,
        };

        // Start the email application on your device to send the Email
        emailcomposer.Show();
    }
```

part of the XAML file:

```
      <TextBlock Text="Wheres the problem" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" 
             FontSize="36" FontFamily="Andalus"/>

    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0,14,0" 
      RenderTransformOrigin="0.463,0.232">
        <TextBox Name="number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="88" Margin="0,98,0,0"   
        TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Please enter your phone number" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="456"/>

        <TextBlock Name="bigText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" AllowDrop="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
           Text="Users will write their problem in here." VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Margin="0,231,0,0" Height="414" Width="456" Foreground="White"/>

    </Grid>
    <Button Name="sendButton" Content="Send your problem" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
      VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,658,0,0" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="#FF996D6D" 
     Background="#FF081359"/>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `TextBlock`. `TextBlock` is only used for displaying text, so you can't edit it (eg, drop text onto it). `TextBox` allows input and will let you drop text into it.

```
<!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0,14,0" 
      RenderTransformOrigin="0.463,0.232">
        <TextBox Name="number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="88" Margin="0,98,0,0"   
        TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Please enter your phone number" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="456"/>

        <TextBox Name="bigText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" AllowDrop="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
           Text="Users will write their problem in here." VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Margin="0,231,0,0" Height="414" Width="456" Foreground="White"/>

    </Grid>
    <Button Name="sendButton" Content="Send your problem" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
      VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,658,0,0" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="#FF996D6D" 
     Background="#FF081359"/>
```